# Why does running Linux eventually cause my ThinkPad T430 to refuse to boot or enter diagnostics?

Tags: bios, centos, hardware-failure, thinkpad, firmware

I have a Thinkpad T430. Every time that I install Linux (Latest CentOS) on it, after a while, the computer refuses to boot, go into bios, or boot / diagnostics menu. I've run Windows on it, and it doesn't happen until I decide to switch to, or dual boot CentOS.

This has happened with three motherboards so far, which I've had to replace. Now I'm on my fourth one, and I'm debating whether I am just one unlucky person who keeps ending up with defective hardware, or is Linux somehow corrupting the motherboards' firmware.

What do you guys think?

Does this make sense from a technical point of view? Maybe the T430 isn't compatible with Linux?  Feel free to speculate.

Comment: Ive same Laptop and with Debian and Windows Running fine, can u should post some pictures about your error?

Comment: Linux isn't able to corrupt the BIOS firmware.

Comment: First time it was just stuck on the Thinkpad boot screen logo (when you first turn on the computer), before that, there was some weird behavior, example: my boot driver appeared several times on the boot menu, and you could apparently scroll down forever.

Comment: What makes you suspect that this is a BIOS corruption?  Is it possible that CentOS is unbootable on your configuration, causing the laptop to go to BIOS diagnostics instead?  It could be that some required driver is missing.  Googling suggests that other T430 users are able to install Centos, so you might want to check your hard drive for bad sectors, and run a thorough RAM test.

Comment: There may be coreboot support for your system.  http://www.coreboot.org/Supported_Motherboards

Comment: @GuitarPicker I know it's a bios failure because it is stuck on the boot screen. I wasn't able  to access the bios settings, or the boot menu, or run diagnostics. So, even if I wanted to try another operating system, I wouldn't be able to since the system doesn't even initialize hardware such as the hard drives.

Comment: Thanks.  I misread your original description.  FYI, the T430 is listed on the link that @ultrasawblade posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a relatively recent device, it doesn’t have legacy BIOS but UEFI firmware. Unfortunately, UEFI is extremely complex and prone to the strangest errors.

For example, a few years ago, Samsung shipped some notebooks which could be bricked by writing too much data into an NVRAM variable, [see here](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Booting-Linux-using-UEFI-can-brick-Samsung-laptops-1793958.html) and [here](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html):

> [...] There's code in the kernel to make this easier on UEFI systems. Whenever a severe error is encountered, the kernel copies recent messages to the UEFI variable storage space. They're then available to userspace after a reboot, allowing more accurate diagnostics of what caused the crash.
>
> That crash dump takes about 10K of UEFI storage space. Microsoft require that Windows 8 systems have at least 64K of storage space available. We only keep one crash dump - if the system crashes again it'll simply overwrite the existing one rather than creating another. This is all completely compatible with the UEFI specification, and Apple actually do something very similar on their hardware. Unfortunately, it turns out that some Samsung laptops will fail to boot if too much of the variable storage space is used. We don't know what "too much" is yet, but writing a bunch of variables from Windows is enough to trigger it. I put some sample code here - it writes out 36 variables each containing a kilobyte of random data. I ran this as an administrator under Windows and then rebooted the system. It never came back.

It’s certainly not impossible for Lenovo to make a similar mistake.

Of course, you should make sure you have the latest firmware update installed.

Comment: Thank you. Although this is speculation (thanks for heeding my request), this seems to be the likeliest explanation for such a random failure.

Answer (score -1):

It is able if you used specific software to flash BIOS, but it doesn't occur if you not use them.

From a little search, it doesn't seem other people having this problem. Check if you broke the key. If you are using EFI, you should use the advanced options in windows to go to firmware options.